# Visual Basic Not using Replace or remove, only Length, Substring and Indexof

Tags: vb.net, string, replace, indexof

Trying to write a program that replaces and removes certain words WITHOUT Replace or remove methods. Only using functions like: Length, Substring, IndexOf.

Example: I type in the input "I love the bikes at Fives Bike Shop."

The output would be: "I love the bikes at 5BS."

The code is below:

```
S = txtIn.Text
'Put a space
S = " " & S
output = ""
Acro = ""
Dim L As Integer
L = S.Length
Dim P As Integer
Dim ending, beginning As Integer

For P = 1 To L - 1
    If Acro.Length >= 25 Then
        ending = S.IndexOf("Five Bike Shop", beginning)
        beginning = S.IndexOf("s", beginning) + 1
        Acro = S.Substring(ending)
        output = output & S.Substring(ending) & "5BS"
    End If
Next
txtOut.Text = output
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Indexof is not a vba function.  Do you mean vb.net?  vba<>vb.net.  You will get better help if your tags are accurate.

Comment: I don't understand ; "Only using pre-defined string methods" Replace is one of those pre-defined method ; what's wrong with it ?

Answer (score 3):

```
Function MyReplace(input As String, oldValue As String, newValue As String) As String
    Dim index = 0
    Dim output = ""
    Dim searchIndex = input.IndexOf(oldValue)

    Do Until searchIndex = -1
        output &= input.SubString(index, searchIndex - index) & newValue
        index = searchIndex + oldValue.Length
        searchIndex = input.IndexOf(oldValue, index)
    Loop

    Return output & input.Substring(index)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank You @Sehnsucht! It only works for one acronym - I am trying a For Loop in the button to have it go > 1... (e.a if I were to type in the input "Five Bike Shop, Five Bike Shop" it would come out " 5BS, 5BS"   Private Sub btconvert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btconvert.Click

 Dim input, Output, old, newer As String

 Dim P As Integer
 Dim L As Integer
input = CStr(txtIn.Text)
L = input.Length
old = "Five Bike Shop"
newer = "5BS"
 For P = 1 To L - 1
Output = MyReplace(input, old, newer)
txtOut.Text = Output
 Next

Comment: What ? the same thing said clearly please ? If what you wanted to say is that it only replaces one occurrence ; then [I beg to differ](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mTCRf2) the behaviour (unless I've made a mistake) is the same as String.Replace (it just lacks argument validation)